# Can a Gnome Ranger use his Animal Companion as a Mount?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, animal-companions, mount, gnomes

We have a new player in our group playing a forest gnome ranger. Now that he has hit 3rd level, he is wondering if his character is small enough / light enough to ride a panther animal companion as a mount.

Can a gnome ranger use his animal companion as a mount?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

## Yes, if your DM thinks a panther has the right anatomy.

The gnome is Small (PHB 37) and the panther Medium (PHB 308). The relevant rule says:

> A willing creature that is at least one size larger than you and that has an appropriate anatomy can serve as a mount (PHB 198)

Your ranger's animal companion is certainly willing. It does depend on whether your DM agrees that a panther has the relevant anatomy, but riding felines is a [solid fantasy trope](https://web.archive.org/web/20150304180234/http://www.planeteternia.de/grafiken/userfiles/205353.jpg) even if it is 'unrealistic' to think felines have the proper [back](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_%28horse%29).

*Respect to @SevenSidedDie for the links above. By the Power of Grayskull may his comment never be removed from this answer!*

Comment: Also gnome ranger riding a panther is ridiculously awesome, but I'm not sure the rule of cool has become a core D&D rule...yet!

Comment: In reality a great cat doesn't have the "right" anatomy (lack of the [specialised musculature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_%28horse%29) needed to bear a rider), but [Skeletor is awesome and disagrees](https://web.archive.org/web/20150304180234/http://www.planeteternia.de/grafiken/userfiles/205353.jpg) so that's a strong argument to consider for overriding realism.

Comment: If [a weasel can ride a woodpecker](http://www.theguardian.com/environment/2015/mar/03/weasel-and-woodpecker-combo-soar-to-top-of-online-charts), surely a gnome on a panther is plausible enough. ;p

Answer (score 6):

I would think that being quadrapedal without any spines or physical anatomy stopping someone from mounting it would count as "appropriate anatomy."  I mean while having a longer, more flexable spine without as much support as some animals that can be ridden might not make it an ideal mount, it is plausable. Other than not having a mane to hold onto; maybe it will need an appropriate harness.
    A panther should be able to handle the weight of a forest gnome; with a base weight of 35-40lbs. Leopards can carry animals weighing up to 3x their body weight into a tree to eat, and male leopards can weigh up to 200lbs. They are the stronger climbers of the pathers, but still  a fair example. Tigers are the larger and stronger of the panthers and and weigh between 150 and 675lbs (Siberian). A 150lb tiger may look a little funny or have trouble with a 40lb gnome and gear, but the larger ones should be able to 'theoretically' handle it. 
    In the end of course, it is the DMs call, but I dont think it can be ruled out based purely on anatomy and physics.